# Flex text field do not work under MacOS X

Tags: apache-flex, flash, macos

Strange problem. Text fields in my flex simply do not work under Mac. Inputted characters do not appear within it. I do not have any specific font set (just _serif), so I don't thing it's font issue.

In what direction should I dig? Have anyone similar experience?

Comment: in which language are you trying to enter the text?

Comment: Could you post the code? I'm on a Mac here at work and have been able to get textFields to show up properly...

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a completely new project with no formatting of any kind. Create a single text field and see if that shows up. 
You may want to consider removing the _serif css to see if that has any effect.

See [Soliant's blog](http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/category/adobe-flex/) for other helpful flex examples